# Spring persistent framework which supports data class of kotlin

Tags: spring, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, immutability

the question is simple, but I can't find any of answer about this.

After searching, I realize that kotlin data class is not suitable for Spring JPA because data class is immutable and does not support inheritance.

So, I wonder are there any alternatives for JPA which support data class.

Thanks,

Comment: I came across this https://kotlinexpertise.com/hibernate-with-kotlin-spring-boot/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find two kotlin-based ORM, [ktorm](https://www.ktorm.org/) and [exposed](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed).

It seems both are very good for start, and it supports data class.
But, at some point, I thought that I need to move to [ktor](https://ktor.io/) rather than Spring boot when I wanna use kotlin more kotlin-tic way..